# Merge lists in columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I've got a dataframe with lists in two columns. It looks like this:

```
    column1    column2             column3
0   text       [cat1,cat2,cat3]    [1,2,3]
1   text2      [cat2,cat3,cat1]    [4,5,6]
```

The values in column3 belong to the categories in column2. How can I get a dataframe that looks like this?

```
    column1    cat1     cat2      cat3
0   text         1        2         3
1   text2        6        4         5
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `explode` to break the values in your lists into separate rows and use `pivot_table`:

```
df.explode(
    ['column2','column3']
    ).pivot_table(index='column1',columns='column2',values='column3',aggfunc='first').reset_index()
```

prints:

```
index     column1 cat1 cat2 cat3
0          text    1    2    3
1         text2    6    4    5
```